# EntityFramework Code first foreign keys error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

There are many questions like mine, but i think i'm doing everything right and i don't see the mistake here is code :

```
public class Card
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string AccountNumber { get; set; } // or string ??

        public decimal TotalFunds { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }

    }


  public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Username { get; set; }

        public string AuthCode { get; set; }

        public string SessionKey { get; set; }

        public string AccessToken { get; set; }

        public virtual Card Card { get; set; }

        //public virtual UserType UserType { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Vehicle> RentedVehicles { get; set; }

        public User()
        {
            this.RentedVehicles = new HashSet<Vehicle>();
        }

        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

And i get the mistake `Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'VehicleRental.Models.Card' and 'VehicleRental.Models.User'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.` 
I have done this several times (connection 1:1 with virtual properties and it always worked), but now i'm stucked with this problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need `[Required]` flag in one of the foreign keys User or Cards or you can define your relationship principles on `OnModelCreating`.

[See this example:](http://blog.bennymichielsen.be/2011/06/02/entity-framework-4-1-one-to-one-mapping/)

I hope this will solve your problem!

Comment: Yea, that's nice with only one [Required] the job is done, but is there a way i can put two columns in DB -> like (in users table) CardId and (in cards table) UserId

Comment: Yes you can redefine the whole relationship between the entities in the OnModelCreagting than you have more free space. mark this answer if it solve your Problem. thanks